# Why is my javascript regex pattern not catching multiple instances?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting back in the swing of things and am stuck on this regular expression.

```
'2s3d3s'.match(/\d\D+/);
```

Why is this not returning `['2s, '3d', 3s']`?

I specified the regex to capture multiple instances but it's only catching the first instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `/g` modifier (used to perform a global match rather than stopping after the first match) to find all occurrences of a match.

```js
console.log('2s3d3s'.match(/\d\D+/g));
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks a bunch. I'll mark it as correct in a few minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @DanRubio No problem.